# Using List<int> in Url.Action Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

i am writing code for search page and i have to pass some filters to the action and depending on those input I have to generate hyper links, hence i am using Url.Action function to generate links.

below is my code

```
@Url.Action("Index","Search",new SkillKindleWeb.ViewModels.Search.SearchRawInput()
{
  CategoryIds = Model.Request.CategoryIds,
  SubCategoryIds = Model.Request.SubCategoryIds,
  StartDate = Model.Request.StartDate,
  EndDate = Model.Request.EndDate,
  StartPrice = Model.Request.StartPrice,
  LocationGroupIds = Model.Request.LocationGroupIds,
  LocationIds = Model.Request.LocationIds,
  EndPrice = Model.Request.EndPrice,
  City = Model.Request.City,
  PageNo = 1,
  SearchQuery = Model.Request.SearchQuery,
  Segment1 = Model.Request.Segment1,
  Segment2 = Model.Request.Segment2,
  TargetAge = Model.Request.TargetAge
})
```

and it is generating url like this

http://someDomain.com/ncr/classes?CategoryIds=**System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.Int32%5D**&StartDate=03%2F30%2F2013%2000%3A00%3A00&StartPrice=0&EndPrice=140000&PageNo=2

My expected Url was

http://SomeDomain.com/ncr/classes?CategoryIds=9&StartDate=3/30/2013&StartPrice=0&EndPrice=140000

Comment: What is `SearchRawInput`? Looks like that your `List<Int32>` is converted to `string` and `StartDate` is not formatted like as you want.

Comment: It seems like your CategoryIDs is not a single value but is a list. Is that what you want.?

Comment: yes i  want it to give me a string like CategoryId=1&CategoryId=2

Comment: SearchRawInput is a view model

Comment: @rajansoft1 You should have included that very helpful comment above of yours in your question at first. I didn't think of what you actually want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about converting it to string representation yourself like that:

```
@Url.Action("Index","Search",new SkillKindleWeb.ViewModels.Search.SearchRawInput()
{
  CategoryIds = string.Join(",", Model.Request.CategoryIds),
  SubCategoryIds = string.Join(",", Model.Request.SubCategoryIds),
  StartDate = Model.Request.StartDate.ToShortDateString(),
  EndDate = Model.Request.EndDate.ToShortDateString(),
  StartPrice = Model.Request.StartPrice,
  LocationGroupIds = Model.Request.LocationGroupIds,
  LocationIds = Model.Request.LocationIds,
  EndPrice = Model.Request.EndPrice,
  City = Model.Request.City,
  PageNo = 1,
  SearchQuery = Model.Request.SearchQuery,
  Segment1 = Model.Request.Segment1,
  Segment2 = Model.Request.Segment2,
  TargetAge = Model.Request.TargetAge
})
```

That is what a viewmodel should be for. That you convert and format all the values you need in the way the view expects it.
Notice that I added a `ToShortDateString()` to your dates as well, since it seems you are not interested in the time part.

Comment: What will happen when my list is empty?

Comment: If your list is empty (means count=0) then the resulting string is an empty string.